# How to force fs.createReadStream to read line as text

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I am using node's fs.createReadStream and related .on function to read a text file line by line and add its content to a div in a webpage. everything has been working fine until I got to the following line:

internalField   uniform (0 0 0);

instead of adding the above line to the div in the webpage it instead adds:

internalField nonuniform List

it appears to be trying to interpret the uniform (0 0 0) as a list. I did a follow-up check where I split the above line using spaces and printed the resulting parts out to console and the list part showed up as List < vector >. is there a way I can indicate I don't want that and for it to just take the text as is and use it?

Thanks, Edward

Edit: adding code that reads the line as requested:

```
// i create the stream
var input2 = fs.createReadStream(myFileName);

// i use the 'readline' to create a reader
var rl2 = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: input2,
  terminal: false
});

// i use the .on function to call a method to add the line to div
rl2.on('line', function(line){
  processLine(line);
});

// in the process method i call another method that uses following
// line to assign the line to the contents of the desired div
document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML += "<code>" + value + "</code>" + "<br>";
```

I've left out some of the smaller details, but i think this gives a top level view of what the main parts of the code are. Thanks.

pic of line from source text file:
[image]

pic showing the output from where i split the line at spaces then looped and used console.log to print out the value for each part to the browser's console. the first line shows the full line on one line. the lines under that show each piece of the original line after splitting at spaces:
[image]

Comment: Please show us your actual code involved here so we can suggest the precise way to fix it and we don't have to guess what it looks like.  `fs.createReadStream()` doesn't do any interpreting of the data it reads on its own so if something it changing the data that is read from the file, it must be something else involved in your code.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there are no `<` and `>` characters in the string you're adding to your div?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for taking the time to look at my question. i've added a summary of the main code lines involved. thanks.
ps. do you think the <code> tag in the html line at end of code would cause this?

Comment: You still have me confused.  `require('readline').createInterface(...)` is something that exists in nodejs.  `document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML` is something that only exists in a browser.  How can those two be in the same body of code?  It appears that some of the "details" you've left out are required in order to understand how this code really works.

Comment: What is the exact text in your file?

Comment: The code comes from two *.js source files. they both are part of an Electron app which includes node.js modules and allows one to make use of a html type page layout for the main gui layout. the last line gets "inserted" into that html page. the first lines are part of the *.js file that makes use of the node.js module to read a file to get the content. hope that helps.

Comment: Well, there's still not enough code here to follow the flow and understand what might be happening.  Did you just add a `console.log(line)` and see exactly what you're getting from the file?  FYI, `xxx.innerHTML += someHTML` is really inefficient.

Comment: i will add pic of file line above in question at bottom

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inserting that text into the page.  So, something somewhere in code you aren't showing us is apparently modifying something.  Or there's something messed up in where you're inserting it into the HTML.  I'm going to take a break from this question because there just isn't enough information here to have any idea what's going on.  There's also no debugging information at all.  You should undertake elementary debugging with `console.log()` statements to follow the content you're reading and inserting.

Comment: ok. thanks for feedback. i did add console.log statements to investigate. i'll do that again and include output in question in case someone sees something. thanks.